# What is the proper way to compare an element of an std::string with a character?

Tags: c++, string, char, element, cstring

I am not a very experienced C++ programmer,  i get a warning when i do the following:

```
if (myString[i] != 'x')
{
}
```

what is the appropriate way to compare these?

thanks for your help!

Comment: What warning are you getting?  I see nothing inherently wrong with this code

Comment: I get no warning on G++ - what warning are you getting?

Comment: bah i was using a long long int,  your comments led me to it thank you!

the warning was:
warning C4244: 'argument' : conversion from 'unsigned __int64' to 'unsigned int', possible loss of data

Comment: Is myString full of wide characters (unicode)?  If so, you would have to do, myString[i] != L'x'

Comment: @Jorge, a bit of advice for the future: You can edit your own question ('edit' link below the tags), and if you figure out the answer to your own question, feel free to put it in as an answer below, so your question shows up as answered (you can also accept your own answer after 48 hours)

Comment: Now that someone has answered it, he can't delete his own question (I don't think). But he can add his own solution as an answer below and accept it, or accept Jorge's.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

possibility 1:
the int that identifies the element in the array should not be larger than a regular int.

possibility 2:
If myString is of type std::wstring  the appropriate comparison is `myString[i] != L'x'`
(ty popester!)